# Unable to convert field data-type

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I am reading the contents of a field from a linked server with an openquery statement without any problem.  The field's data type is `char(1)`. However if I try to convert to a different data-type, the openquery fails.

Neither of the statements below will work:

```
select * from  FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 
  'select CONVERT (NVARCHAR(),QCTL.GL_TRANS.TRAN_TYPE) AS TRAN_TYPE'

select * from  FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'select 
  IIF(QCTL.GL_TRANS.TRAN_TYPE = ''C'', -1 * QCTL.GL_TRANS.AMOUNT, 
  QCTL.GL_TRANS.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either specify a length when converting or remove the ().

```
select * from FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1),QCTL.GL_TRANS.TRAN_TYPE) AS TRAN_TYPE'

select * from FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'select CONVERT(NVARCHAR,QCTL.GL_TRANS.TRAN_TYPE) AS TRAN_TYPE'
```

Comment: I did try that before, but it also does not work.  The problem occurs only when it is part of the openquery statement.  In other words it will work like this:     select convert(nvarchar,TRAN_TYPE) from openquery(linkedserver, ' select TRANTYPE FROM...')

Comment: Then why cant you just convert it when you get your dataset as you did above?

Comment: I need to do a calcution in the openquery statement (if the tran_type is 'c' then change the amount field by multiplying by minus 1) .  Then, in the outer select query the calculated amounts are summed (both positive and negative amounts.

Comment: Just use a Store Procedure instead, if you doing calculations across networks. 
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'EXEC Database.dbo.StoredProcedure')